# Чем проверить валидность архивной(CAdES-A) подписи?

Tags: криптография

Есть архивная(CAdES-A) подпись. Каким инструментом проверить валидность этой подписи?

Comment: Вас интересует готовая утилита или же библиотека для какого-либо языка программирования?

Comment: Хоть что нибудь. Сейчас рассматриваю secureblackbox - она смотрит по набору атрибутов. А с валидацией самих атрибутов пока не разобрался.
В идеале, конечно, какую-нибудь утилиту, на вход которой можно подать подписанный контент и саму подпись.

Comment: https://crypto.kontur.ru/verify# пойдёт?